# I need log4j v4 equivalent of log4j v2 PropertyConfigurator.configure

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am switching from log4j version 1 to
log4j version 2. I need to duplicate
the functionality of the method with this signature:

```
org.apache.log4j.ProperyConfigurator.configure(InputStream s);
```

That is, I need to programmatically set the
log4j properties from an InputStream. Using
an explicit log4j.properties file is not
an option in my environment.

Also note that this is for a client,
not a server/servlet.

How do I do the equivalent in log4j version 2?

Comment: I found a way to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092422/is-there-a-log4j-2-config-api-that-takes-input-stream-like-1-x-propertyconfigura

Answer (score 0):

From the [looks of it](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), there's no easy way and you may have to [extend log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html) and define your own implementation of [ConfigurationFactory](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html)

Answer (score 0):

Before you write any custom code, I'd recommend asking your question on the log4j user mailing list. That may save you some effort.